# Sklearn vectoring a document by sentences for classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, classification, sklearn-pandas

```
temp = []
for i in chunks:
    vectorizer2 = CountVectorizer()
    vectorizer2.fit_transform(i).todense()
    temp.append(vectorizer2)
    print(vectorizer2.vocabulary_)

x = [LinearSVC_classifier.classify(y) for y in temp ]
```

I have a document that I am trying to put in the proper format to use my classifiers against. I have broken down the doc into individual lists. So the data looks  like this..

```
chunks = [[ 'sentence1'] , ['sentence2'], ['sentences']]
```

The function I have written gets me partially there but then I get this error. 
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words 
but also getting this...

```
{u'and': 4, u'www': 53, u'is': 25, u'some': 44, u'commitment': 10}
```

If I run each sentences manually and individually they each work with 0 errors and the classifier works. I am hoping my results at the end would look like this.

```
['sentence1', 'no'] , ['senence2', 'yes']
```

or anyway i can see each sentences classification works honestly. I am just unsure where the error lies and if it is fixable or I need a new approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-608-c2fb95ef6621> in <module>()
  4 for i in chunks:
  5     print (i)
----> 6     vectorizer2.fit_transform(i).todense()
  7     temp.append(vectorizer2)
  8     print(vectorizer2.vocabulary_)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.pyc in fit_transform(self, 
raw_documents, y)
867 
868         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
--> 869                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
870 
871         if self.binary:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.pyc in _count_vocab(self, 
raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
809             vocabulary = dict(vocabulary)
810             if not vocabulary:
--> 811                 raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the 
documents only"
812                                  " contain stop words")
813 

ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the initialization outside the loop like this, else it will be re-initilized again and again for each sentence seperately which is incorrect.

```
temp = []
vectorizer2 = CountVectorizer()   #<--- This needs to be initialized only once
for i in chunks:

    vectorizer2.fit_transform(i).todense()
    temp.append(vectorizer2)
    print(vectorizer2.vocabulary_)

x = [LinearSVC_classifier.classify(y) for y in temp ]
```

Comment: unfortunately did not fix it. Still getting the stop words error. I dont understand how it can not have issues individually and now it does.

Comment: Can you please do me a favor and add `print i` statement before `
    vectorizer2.fit_transform(i).todense()`, i want to see at which line it is failing

Comment: i added the print i above ` vectorizer2.fit_transform(i).todense()`, I dont really see any differences. I updated the stack trace with the new code for you.

Comment: If i do print temp at the end i get this for each sentence...                
    [CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error='ignore',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)]